# querying and selecting specific column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

How do I select specific columns from a query.
For example, just the User name and size of a photo from:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id =      Column(String,   primary_key = True, unique = True)
    real_name =    Column(String,   nullable = True)

class Photo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'photo'
    url =        Column(String,        primary_key = True, unique = True)
    size =       Column(Integer,       nullable = False)
    ts_taken =   Column(DateTime,      nullable = True)
    user_id =    Column(String,        ForeignKey('user.user_id'))
    user = relationship(User, backref='photos')
```

I can use:

```
s.query(Photo).join(User.photo).all()
```

or maybe, if I want all the photos of a specfic user:

```
s.query(Photo).join(User.photo).filter(User.user_id == '1234').all()
```

But how do I make it return just the User.real_name and the size?

Answer (score 20):

Specify what you want returned in `.query()`.  The first mapped column indicates the base table to query from.

```
session.query(User.real_name, Photo.size).join(User.photos).all()
```

This will get you a list of tuples like `[('name', 12)]` for every photo.

Please consider [searching the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying) briefly.  It's author is *very* thorough.