# How to return rows from query using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With my current code, I'm able to return a dictionary with all data from a given table ( server, port, user and environment), But how could I return only, for example, only user and environment?

```
engine_str = con_string.format(
    login=login, passwd=pwd, hostname=hostname, port=db_port, db=db_name
)

try:
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    connection = engine.connect()
    session = session(bind=connection)
    Base = declarative_base()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
    raise

def select_data(server, trigger_name):
    _t = Table('trigger_details', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    try:
        stm = session.query(_t).filter_by(
            server=server, trigger_name=trigger_name
        )
        column = [c["name"] for c in stm.column_descriptions]
        return [dict(zip(column, row)) for row in stm.all()]
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Comment: Do you mean `session.query(_t.c.user, _t.c.environment)...`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä it doesn't work, it returns "sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <type 'NoneType'>", i'm going to check it out.

Comment: When selecting columns only instead of entities, use `filter()` instead of `filter_by()`, so `filter(t.c.server == server, t.c.trigger_name == trigger_name)`, since `filter_by()` [extracts the keyword expressions from the primary entity of the query, or the last entity that was the target of a call to Query.join()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by).

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you for your replies, I already solved it. posting the solution  in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
engine_str = con_string.format(
    login=login, passwd=pwd, hostname=hostname, port=db_port, db=db_name
)

try:
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    connection = engine.connect()
    session = session(bind=connection)
    Base = declarative_base()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
    raise

def select_data(server, trigger_name):
    _t = Table('trigger_details', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    try:
        stm = session.query(_t.c.user, _t.c.environment).filter(
            server == server, trigger_name == trigger_name
        )
        column = [c["name"] for c in stm.column_descriptions]
        return [dict(zip(column, row)) for row in stm.all()]
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Comment: [The "idiomatic" way is to pass `query()` the columns you need.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012246/querying-and-selecting-specific-column-in-sqlalchemy) As explained in the comments above you then cannot use `filter_by()`, as that operates on entities. In recent enough SQLAlchemy result tuples have `namedtuple` esque method [`_asdict()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict), which returns the contents of the result tuple as dict.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, Thank you for that advice, I already sent this correction to my coworkers and they are replicating it to our repo.. I'm updating my  answer as soon i have the final working example.