# Querying with joins in sql alchemy and avoiding select all

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I would like to know wether there is a way to combine joining two tables, and retrieving the two entities only with their relevant columns.

I want to avoid doing a thing such select * after joining two tables and getting only column `id` from Table A and column `address` from table B.
Working with python2.7
I heard of sqlalchemy feature called `with_entities`, but not sure how can it be mixed with this kind of join, lets work on this example from [sqlalchemy tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html):

```
u, a  = session.query(User, Address).\
                     filter(User.id==Address.user_id).\
                     filter(Address.email_address=='jack@google.com').\
                     first():
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [querying and selecting specific column in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012246/querying-and-selecting-specific-column-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Query.join()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html)

```
id, address  = session.query(A.id, B.address).\
             join(B, B.user_id == A.id).\ 
             filter(A.email_address=='jack@google.com').\
             first()
```

This can be done using a `join` or `outerjoin` depending on the use case, joins can be implicit or explicit. The `.join` second argument is the explicit join statement.

Comment: If i have identical field names in both models, how should i query it? for example i want to bring the `address` field from both models: `session.query(A.id, A.address, B.address)....`

Comment: You’ll need to label the field using `B.address.label('b_address')`